# Android Studio 64 bit inline ARM assembly

Tags: android-studio, assembly, inline-assembly, arm64

I am trying to run some inline assembly code for aarch64 from Android Studio 3.4.2 and I got a compilation error `error: Don't know how to handle indirect register inputs yet for constraint 'r'`.

My code snippet as follows

```
std::string system_file = "/system/bin/sh";
std::int64_t file_descriptor = -1;

#ifdef __aarch64__
    __asm__ volatile("mov x8, #180\n\t"
                     "mov x0, %1\n\t"
                     "mov x1, #0\n\t"
                     "svc #1\n\t"
                     "mov %0, x0\n\t"
                    :"=r"(file_descriptor)
                    :"r"(system_file)
                    :"x0","x1","x8"
                    );
#endif
```

ARM64 syscalls based on this article

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/arm64-syscalls-table

and taken from

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h

I am not sure if the error is due to Android Studio or am I doing something wrong here? Any advice is appreciated.

**** EDIT ****

I think I may have been looking at the wrong syscall number. Instead, I should be looking at

```
#define __NR_openat 56
__SC_COMP(__NR_openat, sys_openat, compat_sys_openat)
```

Now I am trying to do this and it seems to be wrong.

```
    std::string system_file = "/system/bin/sh";
    const char *ptr  = system_file.c_str();
    std::int64_t file_descriptor = 0;
    register std::int64_t x8 asm("x8") = 56;
    register std::int64_t x0 asm("x0") = 0;
    register std::int64_t x2 asm("x2") = 0;

    __asm__ volatile("svc #1"
    :"=r"(file_descriptor)
    :"r"(x0),"r"(ptr),"r"(x2),"r"(x8)
    :"memory"
    );

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"native_code","file_descriptor: %i",file_descriptor);
```

I can see a number "56" returned in logcat but it is the same number regardless the file exists or not. Is it a coincidence that it is the same as the syscall number?

Comment: I don't have a setup to test this, but is it your intention to pass the *address* of the string to the call?  If so, perhaps using `system_file.c_str()`?

Comment: Don't forget to use a `"memory"` clobber or dummy input operand to tell the compiler that you read the memory pointed-to by `system_file`.  (You can't put a `std::string` by value into one register).  Also you don't need and shouldn't use any `mov` instructions in your template: use `register long callnum asm("x0");`  and so on local vars to get your inputs/outputs in the right registers.  e.g. [iOS ARM64 Syscalls](//stackoverflow.com/a/57092866) is somewhat good.  The same inline asm with Linux call numbers should work.

Comment: Here's an AArch64 Linux example: [How to specify an individual register as constraint in ARM GCC inline assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3929442)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I was experimenting with local register vars for this.  One thing I was not able to confirm is what registers (if any) the `svc` instruction might clobber (other than r0).  I know for example amd64 clobbers rcx & r11, but can't find a similar reference for arm64.  Does it leave everything else alone?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: For Linux, I think so.  The default is that Linux preserves all regs except the return val, except where the syscall instruction itself destroys some (like x86-64 `syscall`).  iOS apparently can return in up to 2 registers and also modifies flags to indicate error or not, but Linux system calls only ever use 1 reg for the return value and encode errors "in-band" with a return value >= unsigned `-4095`

Comment: Thanks to PeterCordes and DavidWohlferd for your comments and advice

Comment: You're programming in C / C++, `#include <asm/unistd.h>` and actually use `__NR_openat` instead of hard-coding a number!  You can even do this in a `.S` file because that header only has macro definitions, not any C code.

Comment: Anyway, you left out an `asm("x1")` declaration on `ptr` to make sure `"r"(ptr)` picks register `x1`.  Look at the compiler-generated asm.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you want to move as much of the code out of the inline asm as possible.  In this case for instance, you are moving #180 to x8 to indicate the service number to invoke.  But what if you want to open 2 files in a row, passing 180 in x8 both times?  Ideally you'd want to avoid setting the identical value into the same register twice if you could, right?  But by putting the `mov` inside the asm, you are forcing the value to be set every time.

You can avoid that by moving the assignments out of the asm.  While I don't have an arm64 platform to run this on, the output from godbolt looks right:

```
std::string system_file = "/system/bin/sh";
const char *ptr  = system_file.c_str();
register std::int64_t file_descriptor asm("x0");
register std::int64_t x8 asm("x8") = 180;
register std::int64_t x1 asm("x1") = 0;

__asm__ volatile("svc #1"
                :"=r"(file_descriptor)
                :"0"(ptr),"r"(x1),"r"(x8)
                :"memory"
                );
```

Since x1 and x8 are listed as [inputs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) (ie after the 2nd colon), gcc assumes their value is unchanged.  And since the assignments took place in C code, it knows what values are there too.

The "0" might look a bit odd, but it's saying that `ptr` will be in the same place as parameter #0 (ie file_descriptor, which uses `asm("x0")`).  So the input will be ptr, the output will be file_descriptor, and both use the same register.

I'll also mention that all the `svc` samples I've seen use `svc #0`.

Comment: Thanks David. Are there any articles that I can read online to know more about the syntax that you are using? I am not a developer so I am not too sure about this syntax since I don't use it often.

Comment: I'd say start with the gcc docs linked above. You can see the "0" trick being discussed in the second block of that link (*constraint*). Also, one level "up" in the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) gives you links to all gcc's asm concepts, including using `asm("x8")` as an "Explicit Register Variable." I'd also recommend [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm), since mostly I think using inline asm is a bad idea, but unavoidable in this case since gcc has no svc builtin. Don't forget to mark accept if this answers your question.