# aarch64 g++: MOV in __asm only moves lower 32 bits of a 64-bit value

Tags: c++, c++17, cross-compiling, arm64

I am cross-compiling my code for an aarch64 machine using arch64-linux-gnu-g++ (version 7.5.0) and the standard set to C++17.  My code includes the following:

```
  uint64_t inRef = 0x ... ;  

  ...  

  __asm("MOV X8, %[input_i];"  
      :  
      : [input_i] "r" (inRef)  
      : "x8"  
  );
```

I am packing values into inRef and am trying to have the register X8 hold inRef's value, to be handled later in the program.  When I print out inRef's value I can confirm it does indeed hold a 64-bit value.

However, what I am seeing in my program's execution is that only the bottom 32 bits of inRef are actually passed to X8, even though inRef is an uint64_t and X8, being apart of an aarch64 system, is also 64 bits.  I've tried looking into the constraint character (the "r") but according to the documentation, this should refer to a 64-bit register [1].  I also tried making my code more explicit as in [2], with the following:

```
  register std::uint64_t x7 asm("x7") = 0x ... ;  

  ...  

  __asm__ volatile("MOV X8, %[input_i];"  
      :   
      : [input_i] "r" (x7)  
      : "x8"  
  );
```

Unfortunately, the same error occurs.  I have verified my machine is actually an aarch64 machine and its X registers are indeed 64-bit, so I suspect the issue may be within the code or the compilation.  In summary, how do I move the entirety of a 64-bit variable in aarch64 to a register?

References:
[1] http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100067_0610_00_en/qjl1517569411293.html
[2] [Android Studio 64 bit inline ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355889/android-studio-64-bit-inline-arm-assembly)

Comment: Could you put together a [mcve] that one can compile and test on?

Comment: Can't reproduce your concern; e.g. in https://godbolt.org/z/sPvNPh

Answer (score 0):

What you did actually looks right.

For simple `asm` includes you could use 'indexing' referencing to variables like `%0`, `%1`, etc. Number is index of variable in clobber list

```
void f0 (void* self, uint64_t ref) 
{
    asm volatile("mov x8, %0" :: "r" (ref) : "x8");
}
```

In some cases you might like to enforce 64bit registers with attribute `%x0` for 64bit register, or `%w0` for 32bit register. That is useful case when 32bit value is forced into 64b register.

```
void f1 (void* self, uint64_t ref)
{
    asm volatile("mov x8, %x0" :: "r" (ref) : "x8");
    // asm volatile("mov w9, %0" :: "r" (ref) : "x9"); <-- 'mov w9, x1' is generated, that's unsupported op
    asm volatile("mov w9, %w0" :: "r" (ref) : "x9"); <-- this is fine
}
```

Or use name in clobber as you tried. `x`/`w` attributes still could be used

```
void f2 (void) 
{
    uint64_t ref{0xdeadbeefdeadbeef};  
    asm volatile("mov x8, %x[val]" ::[val] "r" (ref) : "x8");
}
```

Same on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/z6vKqx6bT